# JQuery UI Autocomplete multiple values

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm having a problem with the AutoComplete with multiple values.

I can even re-create it on the jQuery demo site - [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple)
What happens is if you search for something, then delete your search and enter the same search nothing happens. I have tried to turn off caching (setting to 1 like the documentation states, or even 0) assuming that it is related yet had no luck.

To recreate it:

Try A on the demo site (Multiple values), select ActionScript, now select all the text 
, then type 'a' again, and AutoComplete isn't triggered.

Maybe im being picky but if anyone's used AutoComplete and managed to fix this issue it'd be great

Thanks Ben

**Edit:**

I apologise, explained it wrong, only actually happens if you type in the same letter after you've selected the text, guess it isn't too much of a problem im just being nitpicky

Comment: Hi, tested it and it works here. Just wanted to let you know.

Comment: Hmm I've tried in chrome and IE and it doesn't work as i'd expect. If I enter a phrase, then select the text, hit a different letter, a new list of options show, but if I enter the same letter as before no letters show until another letter is shown

Comment: Just tested in Chrome and seems fine

Comment: Seems fine for me in both Firefox 3 *and* IE6, surprisingly (in that I'm surprised when *anything* from this century works in IE6.) Is there maybe some particular way you're doing the operations? When you delete all the text, are you just using the delete key, or are you using a keyboard shortcut (e.g. select-all, then delete)? What browser are you using? Is there a proxy server in your way that may be altering something between you and the servers you're trying this on?

Comment: So, I typed in 'a'. Selected ActionScript. Input field contains 'ActionScript,'. Deleted the text, typed in 'a' again. The list is shown correct. Is there any special thing about deleting your selected text?

Comment: Sorry guys check my edit, I didn't delete the text simply typed the letter with the text selected

Comment: It does the search when you type in the second letter you're looking for. If you select the text a second time there is no problem with it.

Comment: Yeah, just seems strange that the first letter works if different, yet not if the same. Like I said guess i'm just being nitpicky, trying find any potential problems before using it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found sth. here: http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/autocomplete.htm

Your selected text is alerted though. After closing it you can select all cities starting with 'a'.